Python Dash: Numericnput value max, value min relationship
I have a simple NumericInput feature using Python dash. I want the Numericinput to have a range from -100 to 100 with the default value at 0. The problem is when I set the value = 0,  the default value returns the min value. What is strange is, when I set the value = non-zero, the default value is the non-zero value.
E.g. if value = 0, then the initial display is -100 (min) and if value = 1, the initial display is 1.
Is there any work around this?
I tried round(0.0001,1), but that does not work.
import dash_daq as daq


 daq.NumericInput(
                  id='my-numeric-input-1',
    
                  min=-100,
                  max=100,
                  value=0,
    
                 label='Range',
                 labelPosition='top',
                 style={"paddingBottom": 15}),)


This sounds like a setDefault(value if value else min) bug.. I would try setting value='0', maybe the component accepts numeric strings.

Perfect that works, thank you!

As per Eric's comment the answer is to set value ='0'.
